# How to prove that $\vdash \neg \neg (p \vee \neg p)$? (Natural Deduction)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic

I do know that double negation and LEM are equivalent, but can we prove
$$\vdash \neg \neg (p \vee \neg p)$$
without using either of them, in a Fitch-style proof?

Comment: It should be articulated what methods are *allowed*, not merely what is forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can.

*Hint*: assume $\lnot (p \lor \lnot p)$ and derive a contradiction.

The conclusion follows by $(\lnot \text I)$, which is intuitionistically valid.

Answer (score 1):

What you may use is the fact that in intuitionistic logic one can derive from $\lnot(p\lor q)$ that $\lnot p\land\lnot q$ (and vice versa: the two ways to interpret $p$ NOR $q$ are equivalent)*. And substituting $q:=\lnot p$ into those expressions, the second form easily leads to a contradiction. With this, you should be able to prove what you want to without much difficulty.

*The same is **not true** for NAND: while from $\lnot p\lor\lnot q$ one easily deduces $\lnot(p\land q)$, the opposite deduction is not possible in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: I am wondering if De Morgan's laws are equivalent to the law of excluded middle. If so shouldn't I avoid using it either?

Comment: No, you cannot use all of De Morgan's laws in intuitionistic reasoning. That is why I used "one can derive"; you must check that a justification can be given using intuitionistic logic, rather than say by using truth tables (which is assuming the excluded middle). I invite you to actually do it and see the difference with the NAND rule, about which I added a remark.